# UTF-8 percentage encoding and python

Tags: python, utf-8, url-encoding

I'm trying to get python to give me percent encoded strings. The API I'm interacting with (which I think is using percent encoded UTF-8), gives %c3%ae for î. However, python's urllib.quote gives %3F.

```
import urllib

mystring = "î"
print urllib.quote(mystring)
print urllib.quote_plus(mystring)
print urllib.quote(mystring.encode('utf-8'))
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've executed your code, it prints `%C3%AE`. `%3F`, btw, is `?` char encoded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your file has to encode your string as `utf-8` before quoting it, and the string should be unicode. Also you have to specify the appropriate file encoding for your source file in the `coding` section:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib

s = u'î'
print urllib.quote(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

Gives me the output:

```
%C3%AE
```

Comment: Are you sure that your script is saved as `utf-8` encoded file?

Comment: Nope, was in ANSI. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in Python3 this will be `import urllib.parse` and then `urllib.parse.quote`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're not declaring the encoding your file is using, so Python is inferring it from your current `locale` configuration. I'll suggest you to do this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib

mystring = "î"
print urllib.quote(mystring)
print urllib.quote_plus(mystring)
```

And also **make sure your `file.py` is getting saved to disk with `utf-8` encoding**.

For me that yields:

```
$python ex.py
%C3%AE
%C3%AE
```

Couple of caveats. If your trying this from the interpreter, the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` won't work if your console encoding isn't `utf-8`. Instead, you should change it to whatever encoding your console is using: `# -*- coding: (encoding here) -*-`.

Then, you should decode your string into `Unicode` using `decode` method and passing it the the encoding name your console is using as argument:

```
mystring = "î".decode('<your encoding>')
```

And later pass it to `urllib` encoded as `utf-8`:

```
print urllib.quote(mystring.encode('utf-8'))
print urllib.quote_plus(mystring.encode('utf-8'))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. File was ANSI, hence the problem.