# Wikipedia API: getting articles with unicoded titles

Tags: python, xml, unicode, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to retrieve Wikipedia pages using the titles returned from calling the api.
I am calling Wikipedia API from python's urllib2 library.

I am stuck with handling the unicoded titles when I want to automate the process.
Here is an example of the problem:

Lets assume we want to retrieve the page about *Escola Superior de Ciências Empresariais*, that has the following link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escola_Superior_de_Ci%C3%AAncias_Empresariais_(Set%C3%BAbal)

calling the I do get what I want:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=xml&titles=Escola_Superior_de_Ci%C3%AAncias_Empresariais_(Set%C3%BAbal)&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content

So going to the beginning of the problem, if I also use the wikipedia api to search for the school like:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srprop=''&format=xml&srsearch=Escola_Superior_de_Empresariais](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srprop=%27%27&format=xml&srsearch=Escola_Superior_de_Empresariais)

I get the following xml string:

```
<api>
  <warnings>
    <search xml:space="preserve">Unrecognized value for parameter \'srprop\': \'\'</search>
  </warnings>
  <query>
    <searchinfo totalhits="7"/>
    <search>
      <p ns="0" title="Escola Superior de Ci\xc3\xaancias Empresariais (Set\xc3\xbabal)"/>
      <p ns="0" title="List of universities in Cape Verde"/>
      <p ns="0" title="Polytechnic Institute of Viana do Castelo"/>
      <p ns="0" title="S\xc3\xa3o Vicente, Cape Verde"/>
      <p ns="0" title="Economy of Portugal"/>
      <p ns="0" title="Higher education in Portugal"/>
      <p ns="0" title="Grupo Opaia SA"/>
    </search>
  </query>
</api>
```

my question now is that how can we convert the retrieved string

```
Escola Superior de Ci\xc3\xaancias Empresariais (Set\xc3\xbabal)
```

to a form that can be called directly from the Wikipedia API?
That is to say, how can I create a link like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escola_Superior_de_Ci%C3%AAncias_Empresariais_(Set%C3%BAbal)

from the retrieved results?

Comment: Can you just translate `\x` to `%`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters - seems to be the same basic question

Comment: No, but in conjunction with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163009/utf-8-percentage-encoding-and-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use urllib2.quote, which do this for you.

Essentially:

```
utf8_url = 'Escola Superior de Ci\xc3\xaancias Empresariais (Set\xc3\xbabal)'
percent_url = urllib2.quote(utf8_url)
```